# When to compose a Component in the ZK life-cycle?

Tags: java, zk

**The Question:**
In ZK, when working with custom components, what is the best time in the life-cycle to build the component's contents (arbitrarily complex). That is, when can we safely assume we have all data from the view but without waiting too long.

**The Details:**
In ZK, I can create a custom component `MyCoolComponent`:

```
package my.package;

public class MyCoolComponent extends Div {

  private String title;

  public MyCoolComponent() {
    Selectors.wireVariables(this, this, Div.class);
    Selectors.wireComponents(this, this, false);
    Selectors.wireEventListeners(this, this);
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  // When is the correct time to call this function?
  public void initializeComponent() {
    appendChild(new Label(title));
    // arbitrarily complex initialization follows ..
  }

}
```

I can use my custom component in a zul file like so:

```
<?component name="coolcomponent" class="my.package.MyCoolComponent" ?>
<zk>
  <coolcomponent id="cool" height="200px" title="Sean is Cool" />
</zk>
```

Now, when this `Component` is used I want to add children `Components`, for example, by calling the `initializeComponent` function in `MyCoolComponent`.

In the world of `Composers` we are taught to handle all of this kind of work in the `After Compose` phase of the life-cycle with the [`doAfterCompose`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/select/SelectorComposer.html#doAfterCompose%28T%29) function. Is the same true for a `Component` created like this? If so, what is the best (read: efficient, safe, readable) way to do so? I feel like attaching a `@Listen` for the `onRender` event is sloppy. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the [zk docs](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Composing/Composite%20Component#Implement_a_Java_Class), the constructor is like `doAfterCompose`,
if you call the `Selectors` methods like in the example.

But what you like to do could be

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
  this.title = title;
    if(label != null)
      appendChild(new Label(title));
    else
      lebel.setValue(title);
}
```

The zk life cycle is, when entering a zul component `<MyComponent>` 
it calls the constructor, if there is some thing like `title="Sean is Cool"`
it calls the set method, and if this is done for all `Components` it creates the page.
Does this helps you?

### Edit

For more complex structure, there are two options

1. Create a zul file with you needed structure and use [Executions#CreateComponent](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.5.1/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Executions.html#createComponents%28java.lang.String,%20org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component,%20java.util.Map%29) or
2. Create your own [zk-Component-Widget](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Development%20Essentials/Creating%20a%20simple%20ZK%20Component) package

What is the right one for your purpose?

- Choose 1. if you have a structure of zk Components you want to (re)use.
  A structure of a forum post could be such a thing.
- Choose 2. if you want to
  add special functionality,
  optimize/costumize client-server communication,
  write a binding for a JavaScript lib,
  keep memory size small at client side,
  (even for complex structure you just need one class)
  ... .
  There are for sure many benefits of own Components,
  but it takes time to implement them.

Now what's about the life-cycle? For option 2 just read the doc.
For option 1, do it in `doAfterCompose` or in an event listener/handler.

Ok here is an Example for option 1.

The main zul

```
<zk>
  ...
  <div id="menu" use="myPkg.MyMenu" item1="omg" />
  ...
</zk>
```

my menu definition

```
<vbox>
  <label id="item1" value="${arg.item1}">
  ...
</vbox>
```

java

```
class MyMenu extends Div {
  String item1;
  ...
  public void setItem1(String x){
    item1 = x;
  }

  // onCreate is fired before data is send to the client,
  // but after the Component and all it children exists.
  public void onCreate(CreateEvent ev){
    Executions.CreateComponents("MenuDef.zul", this, new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
        put("item1", item1);
    }});
  }
}
```

You could call `Executions.CreateComponents` in the `doAfterCompose`
from your main zul as well, but of course if you want to set values
in zul the `onCreate` way is better.
To add the components by java inside the `onCreate()` works fine too,
but it is more redable / maintainable if you write things down in a zul.

Now to awnser you question in one sentence:
The best time is to init your `Components` is in `doAfterCompose` and by listing to the `Create Event`.

Comment: Did some edit, it may helps you. If not, what is your problem or what do you think could be a problem?

Comment: Eeeh, I'm very against overloading setter methods. When someone sees a setTitle in the API, convention suggests they can assume it does just that one thing. Affecting the DOM from a setTitle function would be a poor design choice for me.

Comment: Keep in your mind, that this is a `View` class and if you set some thing in a view, you must update what is shown. So what do you want to do? What do you tink zk is doing in its `Components`? Take a look inside the zk classes.

Comment: I understand, but I think it's a very fine line to walk. In this example, I'd say this approach might be acceptable. But in a more complex component with many pieces that need to be built, it would be a lot cleaner to do it in one location, once. Consider not just a Div with a Label, but a navigation bar, or a walkthrough wizard window, etc. I'd really like to know the best place& time to initialize complex custom components like these.

Comment: The question isn't regarding *how to organize code* but, as it's titled, *when to compose* the component. I have **already** chosen the first option you presented. The question is now when do I compose the component. There is no `doAfterCompose` function tied into the ZK life-cycle when taking this approach.

Comment: I wrote "doAfterCompose or in an event listener/handler". But, I think you get me wrong. I will edit and add an example.

Comment: Fantastic, [onCreate](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Events/CreateEvent) looks like an appropriate hook.

Answer (score 0):

In ZK, child node will be created before its parent, you can set value when the onCreate event of child is triggered, or add event listener listening to onCreate event in MyCoolDiv
s constructor then call init in that listener.

For more information, please refer to the sample at zk fiddle [Div test](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3cs2gi5/1-Div-test)

Comment: I've simplified the example to emphasize what I want to do. Adding a Label to a Div isn't my problem. My question is regarding best practices for initializing the contents of a custom component/widget, wether their contents be Labels or something else. What is the best point in the life-cycle and how does one efficiently tap into that?

Comment: In your updated case, I think you can call init method as soon as constructor finished.

Comment: Nope, setTitle hasn't been called at that point.. this is my question.  The code I've provided is an [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions), if you test the code you'll get an NPE with your solution.

Comment: Sorry, was a little bit misunderstanding your question, please see the updated (corrected) answer.